# Android data binding view.onTouchListener

Tags: android, data-binding, ontouchlistener

`Android` in data binding there is

```
<Button android:onClick="@{handler.someButtonClick()}"/>
```

and in its `Handler class` its listener will be some how like:

```
public View.OnClickListener someButtonClick() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        };
    }
```

I want to implement `OnTouchListener` for a `Button` that I could know that when the button is pressed and when it is released

Like:

```
// Check if the button is PRESSED
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
     //do some thing          
}// Check if the button is RELEASED
else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    //do some thing                     
}
```

Is there any possible way to accomplish this task.

Comment: try `android:onClick="@{ (view, event) -> (handler::handleAction(event)) }"`, not tested. But, as documentation says you should only bind simple listeners through data binding as it could be hard to read and maintain later. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#listener_bindings

Comment: Can you provide a sample code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a workaround which you can use to do this.

```
@BindingAdapter("touchListener")
public void setTouchListener(View self,boolean value){
    self.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            // Check if the button is PRESSED
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //do some thing
            }// Check if the button is RELEASED
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //do some thing
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And then in xml

```
<Button  app:touchListener="@{true}"/>
```

Comment: This `setTouchListener(..)` will be in the ViewModel right?

Comment: @Kavita_p , no you should make it an abstract method.

Comment: onTouch method should return true

Answer (score 3):

ViewModel

```
public class RecyclerViewModel   {
      public View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener;

      public void setOnTouchListener( View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener) {
          this.onTouchListener = onTouchListener;
      }
}
```

DataBinding

```
@BindingAdapter("onTouchListener")
public static void setOnTouchListener(View view, View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener) {
    if (onTouchListener != null)
        view.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
}
```

Use in xml

```
<Button app:onTouchListener="@{viewModel.onTouchListener}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel

```
private var tapTime: Long = 0

fun onTouchListener(view:View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
   when (event.action) {
      MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
          tapTime = Date().time
          // more commands for touch down event
      } 
      MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
         if (Date().time - tapDate < 300) {
            view.performClick()
           // more commands if click event
         } else {
           // any commands if holded toch on screen
         } 
     }
  }
  return true
}
```

**No need for data binding adapter. It exists already.**

XML

```
<Button
   ...
   app:onTouchListener="@{viewModel.onTouchListener}"
   ...
  />
```

**Warning**
You need to use the right signature in ViewModel:

```
fun name(view:View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean
```

and right name of the attribute in XML:

```
app:onTouchListener
```